# Does win.document.forms survive navigation?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Does forms below survive navigation? getinfo() will navigate to another document (in win) and then back again and return. Will the code below work?

```
var forms = win.document.forms;

for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
{
    var inputs = forms[i].elements;
    getinfo(inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value);
}
```

Comment: No. Use AJAX instead.

Comment: @Xufox Use Ajax? There is no server I can access directly to get the info. I must navigate to another document by clicking to get it.

Comment: Alternatively `localStorage`

Comment: @Jonasw What is localStorage?

Comment: ^ Google `localStorage` :)